# How we can fetch Source volume id from replica volume id in softlayer

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I want to fetch Source volume id from replica volume id in softlayer. I have tried most of the API's given but did not find any which will fulfill my needs. Can some one please help me to get the API to fetch the correct volume id of source volume from replica volume.

I was hoping the below service/API will help me to get parent volume id .. but it is not. It is giving some other parent id which which is not relevant.

SoftLayer_Network_Storage::getParentVolume

Answer (score 0):

> UPDATE

You could try this requests to retrieve the snapshots associated with this SoftLayer_Network_Storage volume and the parent volume to which all of them belong:

```
https://$username:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/$networkStorageId/getObject.json?objectMask=mask[parentVolume,snapshots[parentVolume]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following rest request:

```
https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/$storageId/getReplicationPartners

Method: Get
```

Replace: **$user**, **$apiKey** and **$storageId** with your own information

References:

- [SoftLayer_Network_Storage::getReplicationPartners](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/getReplicationPartners)